# AttributeError : 'module' object has not attribute 'globe1'

Tags: python, python-import

The directory structure is :

```
ga/ :

    PP.py

    this.py

    that.py

tripathi/:

    nn.py # contains function net

    neuron.py #contains function node

    aicc.py # contains function AICC

    blah.py

    variable.py

    __init__.py
```

---

I am trying to use 'tripathi' directory as a module. Hence, `__init__.py`

```
#__init__.py 

from nn import net

from neuron import node

from aicc import AICC
```

---

```
#variable.py

def initialise (): #to initialise global variables


    global globe1, globe2, globe3

    globe1 = 8

    globe2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

    globe3 = "bakar"
```

---

The file `variable.py` contains some global variables to be used in `this.py`, `that.py`, and `PP.py`

```
#this.py

from tripathi import node 

from tripathi import AICC #function AICC in aicc.py

from tripathi import variables #file variables.py

variables.initialise() #all global variables initialised

this_one = variables.globe1
```

---

Now, that.py has

---

```
#that.py

import this

AttributeError : 'module' object has no attribute 'globe1'
```

Why is there an Error? Does `import this` statement (in `that.py`) not import all the modules imported in `this.py` ?

Edit: 
I am using IPython notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Using the global keyword is not enough. You have to declare the variable on module level:

```
#variable.py

globe1 = 8
globe2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
globe3 = "bakar"

def initialise():
    pass # nothing to do there anymore.
```

Comment: So, if I want to use `globe1` variable in `that.py` ... I need to import variables in `that.py` separately?

Comment: `this.py` works perfectly fine. Still, is there a need to place `globe1` variable outside `initialise()`?